# How to remove number of reads under each node?

Tags: nodes

I'm using Drupal 7. After enabling the Statistics module, I see, under each node, how many times it has been read (e.g. "4 reads"). How can I remove this expression while I'm using it ("Content statistics: Total views") in my views?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According the code of the statistics module, you can just remove the "view post access counter" permission from all roles.

Comment: Does not seem to work for administrator role.

Comment: Yes, sure. Administrators have all rights, always.

Answer (score 8):

I needed a simple page counter but did not want to see the "reads" on every node page even as the site admin. For my drupal 7 "fusion" sub theme I used this in my template.php

```
function yourfusionsubthemename_preprocess_node(&$vars) {


unset($vars['content']['links']['statistics']['#links']['statistics_counter']['title']);



}
```

Comment: that was awesome!

Answer (score 1):

If the permissions don't work, you can also unset it in your `THEME_preprocess_node()` function (in your template.php). Just add the following line:

```
  unset($content['links']['statistics']['#links']['statistics_counter']['title']);
```